# Weak convergence of continous function of $L^2$ functions

Tags: continuity, weak-convergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function and $y_{n}\to y$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ as $n\to\infty$, where  $y_n,y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, $\Omega$ open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that then $f(y_{n})\rightharpoonup f(y)$ weakly in $L^2{(\Omega)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need more assumptions on $f$.

Let be :  $\Omega = ]0,1[$  $, y_n(x) = x^{-1/4}$  $ f(x) = x^2$.
And $f\circ y_n$ not even in $L^2(\Omega)$.